# How to output an empty object to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

Using the json module for Python, I want to be able to output empty objects/arrays into my JSON. But this module seems to just ignore them.

Part of the legacy code I am working with, requires these objects to be defined even if empty.

This is the code:

```
import json
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

json_decoded['empty'] = []
json_decoded['not_empty'] = 'allocation'

with open(filename, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_decoded, json_file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

So to summarise: I want the outputted JSON to have the empty objects but they are ignored.

Edit: An example of the JSON used in the sys.argv[1] is:

```
{
    "some_text": "hello",
    "use_google": false,
    "use_gravatar": false,
    "empty": [],
    "not_empty": "some more text"
}
```

The code basically reads in the existing JSON, into the `json_decoded` variable and then we slightly change the settings by just changing the array, and finally outputting the new array into the file...

It all works fine, but the new JSON will be as follows:

```
{
    "some_text": "hello",
    "use_google": false,
    "use_gravatar": false,
    "not_empty": "allocation"
}
```

You can see its missing the `empty` key - which is the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using version `2.0.9` it's able to generate empty lists in the resulting string:  `json.dumps({'foo':[]})` returns `'{"foo": []}'`. It works as well with your options.

Comment: We're gonna need a [mcve].

Comment: @Emilien you are indeed right. It works fine for me. My collegue (who has the issue) must be running an old version. Will find out. Thanks

Comment: Hah, it works fine for him now. Sorry for wasting your time. Not sure what the issue was, but it _is_ working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked fine. I was told it didn't, and I should have checked.

So the above code all works as it should.

Do I delete the question or leave it here for people to view? Do I accept this as the answer?